# why do we need to introduce mean square continuity and mean square differentiability?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

I keep come across the notion that a functional $G(f)$ is **mean square continuous** in function $f$, or is **mean square differentiable** in function $f$ in a few papers I have been reading recently. My questions are:

1. what is the formal definition of a functional $G(f)$ being **mean square continuous** in function $f$, and being **mean square differentiable** in function $f$， respectively?
2. Why are these two concepts necessary and useful? How are they related to the notion of **continuity** and **differentiability** that we have seen in standard calculus class?

For example, when we have $G(f(x))=(f(x))^2$, in standard calculus class, we learned the chain rule, that is $\frac{d G}{dx}=\frac{dG}{df}\frac{df}{dx}$. How is the **mean square differentiable** of $G$ in function $f$ related to $\frac{dG}{df}$ in the chain rule?

Comment: A quick google search suggests that mean square continuity is related to stochastic processes and Brownian motion.  Reading the Wikipedia page gives me $\{X_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is mean-square continuous at time $t$ if $\lim_{s\rightarrow t} \mathbb{E}[|X_s-X_t|^2] =0$. To see why you need different ideas for stochastic calculus, look up Ito's Lemma and compare that with a standard Taylor series: quadratic variation doesn't vanish the same way with a Brownian motion as compared with a continuous function of a real variable.

Comment: @Renard Thanks, this is helpful. I also noticed the following difference: seems that if $G$ only depends on $f$ at a single point, then we are in the standard calculus case; but if $G$ depends on the entire function, like $G(x,f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+x$, then there is no counterpart in standard calculus describing how $G$ changes when function $f$ changes a bit, which means we need to introduce a distance between two functions to characterize what we mean by changing a bit.

Comment: If you want to treat $f$ as an element of a vector space and perturb $f$ in the sense of a directional derivative, look up Frechet or Gateaux derivatives.